# How do I pass variables to Fastload Script using a wrapper shell script

Tags: sql, linux, shell, unix, teradata

I'm working on teradata fastload scripts and I'm using the LOGON command to establish a connection with the database.

**LOGON DBC_ip/username,password;**

But for security purpose I would like to get the password from a vault like application using a shell script.
Initialy I was trying to create a wrapper shell script that would get the password from the vault and use it in the fast load script.

**wrapper_shell_script**--> **fetch_password($password)** --> **execute fastload script** using **$password**.

Example: LOGON DBC_ip/username,$password;

My question:

Is it possible to use external variables in fastload scripts. if yes, can it done using this process.

Could anyone please help me if this is possible or if there any other bette way to implement this.

Let me know if you need more details

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Seems you want to use TD Wallet: https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-VantageTM-Advanced-SQL-Engine-Security-Administration/July-2021/Logging-on-to-Teradata-Vantage/Storing-Logon-Information-in-Teradata-Wallet

Comment: Hi dnoeth. Yes it is kind of similar to TDwallet. But instead of storing the credentials in tdwallet. I would like to get the password in the shell script and pass it to the fast load script.

Comment: Is it possible to use shell variables in inside fast load script?

Comment: Not directly. You could use a ["here document"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) for this purpose.

Comment: When you provide the password using a shell variable it might be possible for other users to read it.